# Text rendered differently on screen and printer in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have a class for writing texts on screen or printer.

```
public void draw(float scale, Graphics g)
{
    Font font = new Font(fontName, size, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);// new PointF(l + scale * x, t + scale * y);
    rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(g.MeasureString(text, font).Width), (int)(g.MeasureString(text, font).Height));

    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix m = g.Transform;
    g.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
    g.TranslateTransform(x - rect.Width / 2, y - rect.Height / 2);
    g.RotateTransform(angle);
    g.DrawString(text, font, brush, point);
    g.Transform = m;
}
```

The different textblocks are of different font sizes and placed at different x positions at the "page". I place two blocks of diffent size at an x where the text ends in the same position on the screen. When I print the "page" the two words don't end at the same position even if the center seem to be at the same position.

I have searched but not been able to find anything that resolves my problem.

Comment: Well of course. You are setting the GraphicsUnit to millimeters. There is a huge difference in resolution between the screen and the printer. Pixels are a good compromise to make things look almost the same size on the screen and the printer. Not perfect.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the Graphics g is set to points both on screen and printer before this.

Comment: How do you calculate the scale factor you use? You will also want to set the Graphics.dpiX/Y values. I usually prefer to write separate routines, esp. when going to a 2nd page comes into play, where the rules differ even more fundamentally than just page unit and resolution and margins and papersizes..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help or not, but I learned long ago that printers compress spacing differently than screens do.  For example, if you wrote a bunch of letters on a document with tabs and space bar spaces between them, it would look different on the screen than if you printed the document on paper.  Maybe it gives you a place to start?

Comment: There were no whitespace characters i  this. I ended up allocating a big bitmap and doing the drawing on this and then showing both it both on screen and on  printer. I didn't have time to fiddle around anymore.